# Are there any Hindu historians?

Tags: scripture, history

Are there any Hindu historians? If so, are their writings available?

Comment: Are you asking about historians who wrote history books governing sanathan dharma?

Comment: Any brahmin historians who wrote books at kings time

Comment: Do you agree ithihasas and puranas as history? or are you asking about medieval India?

Comment: Ithihasas and Purana is history in the time of Krishna and other I am talking about 1 century historians

Comment: How about Kalahana who compiled the Rajatarangini which lists the history of Kashmir? Does he qualify for your question?

Comment: Do any more historians

Comment: I want historian of 1st century